# Change "Third Party Content" answer for app in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I submitted an app to the App Store yesterday, but now realize I should change by answer I checked for the "Third Party" content Yes/No question.

Is there an easy way to do that? I can't find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reject your binary to change this setting. Remove the build from review using the link at the top of the versions' page, then resubmit a build.

Comment: I still don't get the question again when I upload a new build and select that one

Comment: @DepartamentoB You get the question when you Submit for Review, not when you select the build.

Comment: I add a build, select the build and click "submit". I get only the IDFA question, not the third-party content one. If it's a new binary, it will also ask about encryption, but not third-party content.

Comment: Im facing the same issue, can't see third-party content one

Comment: @Mutawe did you find this option? I am also facing this issue now.